# Contextual closure type '(DataSnapshot, String?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Tags: ios, swift

I am brand new to coding and following a course. I am not sure why this error keeps occurring. I have doubled everything listed in the course videos but it still seems to create the error.

I tried rewriting the code several times. I also tried "fixing" with the suggested issue with arg but the instructor does not have to do that in the course and I am just wondering where I went wrong.

the area comes on the REF line.

```swift
import Firebase

let DB_REF = Database.database().reference()
let REF_USERS = DB_REF.child("users")

struct Service {
    
    static let shared = Service()
    
    let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    
    func fetchUserData(completion: @escaping(User) -> Void) {
        REF_USERS.child(currentUid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let fullname = dictionary("fullname") as? String else { return }
            let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
            
            print("DEBUG: User email is \(user.email)")
            print("DEBUG: User fullname is \(user.fullname)")
            
            completion(user)
```

Comment: Sounds like the closure response returns a snapshot and an optional string value.
Try replacing `(snapshot)` with `(snapshot, string)` and see how that goes

Comment: May I know what Firebase version you are using?

Comment: @Lokesh SN  I tried adding  ```REF_USERS.child(currentUid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot, string) in``` but it still came up with the same error

Comment: Maybe you solved this already. I ran into the same problem. Cleaned build folder, deleted derived data and restarted Xcode. The project builds after that.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me. My errors were

> Contextual closure type '(DataSnapshot, String?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body
>
> Insert ',<#arg#> '
>
> Value of type 'NSObject' has no member 'exists'

[image]

What caused my error was I created a function named **doAnotherThing** and when I used it in the completionHandler, I `misspelled one of the parameters`. In the below example my function **doAnotherThing** should use **paramB** not **param2**

```
myRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { [weak self](snapshot) in

    if snapshot.exists() {
        self?.doSomething(param1: "...", param2: "...")
        return
    }

    self?.doAnotherThing(paramA: "...", param2: "...") // <--- this should be paramB not param2.
}

func doSomething(param1: String, param2: String) { ... }

func doAnotherThing(paramA: String, paramB: String) { ... }
```

I don't know why Xcode didn't point out the error and instead I got the above Firebase errors but once I spelled the parameter correctly everything worked fine.